# double row odd&even with listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

**how to implement this method of odd or even row for custom listview ?**
[image: Listview odd row]

**i want to seprate doubled row in listview

i use this one to on row odd :**

```
final int[] bg = new int[]{ R.drawable.even_row, R.drawable.odd_row };
view.setBackgroundResource(bg[position % bg.length]);
```

**i wrote this for doubled row odd but don't work:

first row :**

```
backgroundColor = 0;
view.setBackgroundResource(bg[backgroundColor]);
```

**second row :**

```
view.setBackgroundResource(bg[backgroundColor]);
backgroundColor = (backgroundColor == 0) ? 1:0;
```

**above code is writed in getView() ((custom listview))

backgroundColor  is a global integer variable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your adapter class:

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    if (itemView == null) {
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    if(position%4<2){ //First double rows
    // Paint it red
        itemView.setBackgroundResource(bg[0]);
    }
    else{ // Second double rows
    // Paint it yellow
        itemView.setBackgroundResource(bg[1]);
    }
}
```

Hope it works as you want